# compiling libjingle, expat error

Tags: swt, scons, expat-parser, libjingle

while installing libjingle, the installation halts because of a missing xmlparse.c

this is the error part of the install...
i do have xmlparse.c in the thirdparty/expat-2.0.1/lib/xmlparse.c, 
any idea what's wrong?

```
File "./../../swtoolkit/site_scons/site_init.py", line 203, in BuildEnvironmentSConscripts
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
scons: *** [build/dbg/obj/third_party/expat-2.0.1/lib/xmlparse.o] Source`third_party/expat-2.0.1/lib/xmlparse.c' not found, needed by target `build/dbg/obj/third_party/expat-2.0.1/lib/xmlparse.o'.
scons: building terminated because of errors.
root@den-pc:~/tejesh/libjingle-0.6.14/talk#
```

Comment: Wild guess: you are missing xmlparse.c

Comment: haha.. :p i have xmlparse .c in the same directory in '/third_party/expat-2.0.1/lib/xmlparse.c'

Comment: Sounds like you're having lots of fun with libjingle :)

Comment: yeah :p lots of fun :p... and thanks for helping me out with those last few questions :D

Answer (score 1):

I actually downloaded the libjingle once I realized it was dealing with p2p, since I work in a similar area and want to check it out.

I downloaded the expat lib and copied it to the third-party directory and compiled it without problems like this:

```
# ../../swtoolkit/hammer.sh expat
```

And here are the results:

```
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: warning: The build_dir keyword has been deprecated; use the variant_dir keyword instead.
File "<myPath>/swtoolkit/site_scons/site_init.py", line 203, in BuildEnvironmentSConscripts
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
________Compiling build/dbg/obj/third_party/expat-2.0.1/lib/xmlparse.o
________Compiling build/dbg/obj/third_party/expat-2.0.1/lib/xmlrole.o
________Compiling build/dbg/obj/third_party/expat-2.0.1/lib/xmltok.o
________Creating library build/dbg/obj/libexpat.a
________Indexing build/dbg/obj/libexpat.a
Install file: "build/dbg/obj/libexpat.a" as "build/dbg/lib/libexpat.a"
scons: done building targets.
```

Could it be something as simple as the directory permissions?

Here's what I have:

```
# ls -al third_party/
...
drwxr-xr-x 12 notroot notroot   4096 2012-05-30 02:14 expat-2.0.1
...

# ls -al third_party/expat-2.0.1/
...
drwxr-xr-x 2 notroot notroot   4096 2012-05-30 02:09 lib
...

# ls -al third_party/expat-2.0.1/lib
...
-rwxr-xr-x 1 notroot notroot 193934 2012-05-30 02:09 xmlparse.c
...
```

Actually all of the files in the `third_party/expat-2.0.1/lib` dir have the same permissions, I just didnt want to list them all here.

Answer (score 0):

The installation was searching for expat-2.0.1 when expat-2.1.0 was installed, guess the README is not fully updated.....The compilation continued on renaming the directory to expat-2.0.1.

Comment: You should probably accept this one then if it best answers your question :)